# Materialize CDN for a few components

Tags: cdn

Is there a way to have a Materialize CSS CDN link that requests a css file containing styling for only the components that I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to use the cdn links for only specific parts as they link to the full files.

If you're trying to cut down on load time i'd copy just the part you need to your own file and reference it locally.

Good luck!